# How to reorder a NSMutable array on the basis of NSString stored into it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have an array of NSString, I want to move a particular NSString onto zero index of that array. I am getting values into array after sorting it.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/exchangeObjectAtIndex%3awithObjectAtIndex%3a) method if you want to swap two strings in the mutable array.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a) and [`-[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).